# Why i'm getting Psych::SyntaxError while translating YAML data back into working objects

Tags: ruby, yaml

Ruby version:  `ruby 2.0.0p576 (2014-09-19 revision 47628) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]`
I'm reading "beginning ruby" book and get stuck at  translating  YAML data back into working objects. (it's worth to mention that while converting working objects into YAML data works fine)
  Please see code blow:

```
require 'yaml'
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end
yaml_string = <<END_OF_DATA
---
- !ruby/object:Person
age: 45
  name: Jimmy
- !ruby/object:Person
age: 23
  name: Laura Smith
END_OF_DATA
```

error occurs

```
2.0.0-p576 :013"> END_OF_DATA
 => "---\n- !ruby/object:Person\nage: 45\nname: Jimmy\n- !ruby/object:Person\nage: 23\nname: Laura Smith\n" 
2.0.0-p576 :014 > test_data = YAML::load(yaml_string)
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 2 column 1
```

I have done some research, intuitively，i think this link [click here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10065) is saying something about this issue . However , I have no idea of what are they talking about due to my "kindergarten" level of ruby language. Wish someone can help me solve this problem  and understand it completely . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some indentation. YML isn't white space agnostic. Try using this data instead:

```
yaml_string = <<END_OF_DATA
---
- !ruby/object:Person
  age: 45
  name: Jimmy
- !ruby/object:Person
  age: 23
  name: Laura Smith
END_OF_DATA
```